# print ZPl commands in windows

Tags: java, zpl

I'm able to print ZPL commands in mac using cups,  but I'm unclear that how can I print the labels in windows machine as there is no CUPS server on windows. when I tested it with note pad, it is printing raw strings but not the processed commands

Answer (score 1):

To print directly from Windows, you can configure/change the driver of your printer to set it to "Generic/Text only", then you can print ZPL with Notepad directly to your printer. Be sure to set printing margins to 0, and to remove header and footer in the layout configuration.